# Shuffle/permutation with repeatition in R

Tags: r, permutation

I have a dataframe called Align1 of 10 rows and 567 columns which look like this

```
          1     2     3     4   ...
  Align1 aaa  gct    atc   tac
  Align2 aca  gct    atc   tag
  Align3 aaa  gca    atg   tag
   ...
```

I would like to shuffle the columns (for example have this order: 2, 4, 1, 3).
I am using this line to do it:

```
Test <- Align1[,sample(ncol(Align1))]
```

At the end, I would like 1000 dataframe shuffled.
My problem is that I would like to allow repeated columns (for example: 2, 4, 3, 2) which is not the case with my script.
Does someone know a way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Add replace=T to sample.

Answer (score 1):

```
Test <- Align1[,sample(ncol(Align1), replace = TRUE)]
```

And here an example of how to create a list with (in this case) 10 dataframe subset with 3 possibly repeated columns:

```
replicate(10, mtcars[, sample(names(mtcars), 3, replace = TRUE)], simplify = FALSE)
```